# playing music by url

Tags: objective-c, qtkit

I want to play the music from internet by url.
I create a simply project that has one button with the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://someURL.mp3"];
NSError **err;
QTMovie *movie = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithURL:url error:err];
[movie play];
```

It works but with some delay (I think because it waits while file has been fully downloaded).
So what I need to do that the music starts to play immediately (when, for example, 10% of file has been downloaded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-[QTMovie autoplay]` to automatically play the music once enough data has been downloaded.

In your case:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://someURL.mp3"];
NSError **err;
QTMovie *movie = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithURL:url error:err];
[movie autoplay];
```

From the [QTMovie class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/QTMovie/autoplay):

> The autoplay method configures a QTMovie object to begin playing as soon as enough data is available that the playback can continue uninterrupted to the end of the movie.

Answer (score 1):

If you can consider displaying a Quicktime window over your app, you can use this code :

```
NSString *url = @"http://someURL.mp3";
UIWebView* tempAudioPlayer = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; 
[tempAudioPlayer loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe frameborder=\"0\" width=\"0\" height=\"0\" src=\"%@\"></iframe>", url] baseURL:nil];
[self addSubview:tempAudioPlayer];
```

I first create a UIWebView which will not be displayed. Then I `loadHTMLString` a `<iframe>` in it, with the URL of my file as the `src` value. And I add it to my view. Quicktime appears immediately.